# how do i make an executable java archive run automatically when i login?

Tags: java

How do I make a executable java archive run automatically in Ubuntu 12.04 lts? i tried going to the start menu and then clicking on start up applications, but when I restarted my computer to see if it worked, I found that it didn't start the program automatically. if it helps, I want to run minecraft automatically on start up. Please help -dkino14

Comment: Tell us how would you open the program from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

## METHOD 1

```
sudo mv /minecraftstartscript.sh /etc/init.d/
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/minecraftstartscript.sh 
sudo update-rc.d minecraftstartscript.sh defaults
```

[From Dave at Stack Exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221757/run-automatically-program-on-startup-under-linux-ubuntu) I do not recommend this for loading minecraft at start. Please note that this creates something that can break your startup if applied inappropriately.

### METHOD 2

My recommend method.

You should also look into the [scripts that gnome (`/home/{username}/.config/autostart`)](https://developer.gnome.org/autostart-spec/) & X server runs to add your

```
/usr/bin/java /path/to/minecraft
```

command to.

1. add the command to run Minecraft to somefilename.desktop as well as a method to verify the network has been properly loaded.
2. move somefilename.desktop to `/home/{username}/.config/autostart/`
3. Profit?